# Appending element with space in string

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am appending an html element using foreigobject in d3js. Here's the html

```
.html(function(d) {return "<span onclick=processParams('"+str+"')><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></span>";})
```

The problem is if the str value contains a space, it breaks. So for a str value of 'xyz' I get the element,

```
<span onclick="processParams('xyz')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
```

But for an str value of 'xyz abc'. it somehow becomes,

```
<span onclick="processParams('xyz" abc')=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know d3js but I can clearly make out that its the quotes which are troubling you and not the space, so escape them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote your attributes.

Your second example is returning the HTML:

```
<span onclick=processParams('xyz abc')><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></span>
```

Since you're not quoting, the value of 'onclick' ends when it hits a space. The remainder (`abc')`) is seen as another param name, with no value.

Try:

```
.html(
  function(d) 
  {
    return "<span onclick=\"processParams('"+str+"')\"><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></span>";
  }
 );
```

Comment: This is very true, but not very d3-ish. See my answer for a more d3-ish way of doing this.

Comment: Certainly valid. I was going for the "help the OP understand what's happening and why" approach.

Comment: That has value as well :) Agreed. +1

Answer (score 3):

Why not do it the d3.js way?

```
.append("span")
    .on("click", function(){
        processParams(str)
    })
    .append("i")
        .attr("class", "fa fa-plus-circle")
```